# ZipOutputStream MemoryLeak

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, application-pool

I am using `ZipOutputStream` to get files from db, compress to zip and download (zip file around `400mb`).
During this, my app pool memory is going up to `1.4gb` and after download is complete, its coming down to `1gb` when it should come back to like `100 mb` or something.
There are only like 10 users using this app and only 1 user using this particular page.
 i am calling the dispose method. I aslo tried explictly calling `GC.Collect` but still no use.
Am i missing anything here?

Thanks in advance.

```
  Dim zipStream = New ZipOutputStream(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream)
    Try


        da.Fill(ds)
        For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            Try
                Dim docName As String = ""
                strImgID = dr("image_id")
                If Not IsDBNull(dr("loan_number")) Then iLoanID = dr("loan_number")

                If Not IsDBNull(dr("document_name")) Then docName = dr("document_name")
                Dim ext As String = dr("image_type_extension")
                Dim strFinalFileName As String = ""

                strFinalFileName = docName & "_" & iLoanID & ext

                Dim b As Byte() = dr("image_binary")
                Dim fileEntry = New ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(strFinalFileName))
                zipStream.PutNextEntry(fileEntry)
                zipStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
            Catch ex As Exception
                LogError(ex, iLoanID & "," & strImgID)
                AddError(sb, ex, iLoanID & "," & strImgID)
            End Try
        Next

     Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    Finally

        zipStream.Close()
        zipStream.Dispose()
          cmd.Connection.Close()
        cmd.Connection.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to chunk data into the stream rather than allocate all at once.

E.g. (in c#)

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

FileStream readFs = File.OpenRead(strFile);

for (int rnt = readFs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); 
      rnt > 0; 
      rnt = readFs.Read(buffer,  0, buffer.Length))
{
      zipoutputstream.Write(buffer, 0, rnt);
}
```

I think this will help with your memory issue. Please comment back if not..

Comment: Given the buffer size, will there be any limit for the size of each file?

Comment: No it will just keep going on. How big are the files?

Comment: any where from 1mb to 50mb. Also i couldnt use the File.OpenRead(strFile); as i dont really have a filePAth. All i have is a binary from database.

Comment: I finally got it to work but still doesnt seem to help. Still keeping around 900mb in App Pool

Comment: Ok will have a look deeper then. And yes that was just using a FileStream as an example you would use something diff.

Comment: Ok so I think there must be something going on with the rest of your code. If you take the zip stream thing out of it how is the memory? I just did a test creating a 500meg zip file and my memory didnt' really go up at all.. What about closing the output stream now you are done? Do you have any output caching or anything?

Comment: Can you try pull out all the code that does just the DB access and the zipping and see if you still have the same problem. Then you can start attaching profilers to it and seeing where the memory is allocated.

Comment: Ya.. I removed all the zip part out and checked. It was actually the dataset da.fill(ds). It is taking a min or to to execute this line and in the meantime the app pool memory in going up to 2 gb.
Apparently, the size of the datatable being returned from stored proc is 1.4gb and is not being released even after the postback is done or the app is closed.I tried even calling ds.Clear n dispose. no use. Not sure why